# Ajax request access jquery instance

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a html base page with jquery included.

Then i have a **partial view rendered inside my base page** with this code, wich replaces #con content with grid data:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.get("@Url.Action("_Grid", "Data")", function (data) {
        $('#con').replaceWith(data);
    });
});
```

This is working perfecly but i need **include jquery again**.

So my question is:

Is there a way from this javascript have refence from the previous included jquery?

Comment: why do you need to include jquery again?

Comment: you should not include it again

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: Post your html. Any chance you are including jQuery within the element where `id="con"`?

Comment: You don't need to include jQuery again. The jQuery is a) not loaded, **b) in a nonConflict mode** - try to change `$` to `jQuery`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I put all scripts in HEAD TAG.

If the application have a consider use of ajax its better set all scripts in head instead on end of html body.